# What value should i give for pg_transport.num_workers, max_worker_processes, pg_transport.work_mem while transporting between DB instances

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am migrating from 2800GB postgreSQL(version 13.12) rds instance (out of 2800GB only 450GB is used) to a new 550GB postgreSQL rds instance, what value should i add to pg_transport.num_workers, max_worker_processes, pg_transport.work_mem

The rds instance type for source account is db.t4g.xlarge and destination account is db.t3.micro
I was following the link and was assigning values for db parameters accordingly
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.TransportableDB.html#PostgreSQL.TransportableDB.Parameters

i tried below values:
configuration 1:

pg_transport.num_workers: 10
max_worker_processes: 33
pg_transport.work_mem: not changed

configuration 2:

pg_transport.num_workers: 6
max_worker_processes: 27
pg_transport.work_mem: 128MB

for both the configuration the transportation is taking long time, around 3% per hour. Is it normal to take this amount of time?

currently the logs are showing like below
[logs after running the transport.import_from_server() funtion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb9Qy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will get much better performance only changing those parameters. 
Please consider [Amazon DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) for that purposes, it should be faster way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, does rds instance type matters in this case?
the rds instance type for source account is db.t4g.xlarge
and destination account is db.t3.micro

Comment: @Athulya, You can use Amazon DMS to migrate a database from one Amazon RDS instance to another! Should no be problems to specify any Amazon RDS as a source or target database

Comment: Here  is how you can create a Replication Task:

In the Amazon DMS console, create a new replication task.
Choose your source and target endpoints. The source endpoint will be your source Amazon RDS instance, and the target endpoint will be your target Amazon RDS instance.
Select the migration type (full load, ongoing replication, etc.) and specify any additional settings for your migration task.